# Getting HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden after login on Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish-4

I'm recently started to learn about Java EE web programming and I arrived to form authentication topic using some JSP pages with Netbeans 8.2 and Glashfish 4.1.1, this video is the tutorial that I was following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXnwtR1lT3w
```

I was follow step by step but when I login with my user and password server only send me a HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden error, I was configure the user in the file realm security section of server-config with 'AppAdmin' as group list.

**This is my login.jsp:**

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <p>Please enter your username and password to login.</p>
        <form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="j_username" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="j_password" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login Now" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my web.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administrative Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrators</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Common Users</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

This is my glassfish-web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <principal-name>admin</principal-name>
    <group-name>AppAdmin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <principal-name>user</principal-name>
    <group-name>AppUser</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I'm stucked on this part I tried some things that I read on some forums with no luck.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old but anyway. Checking my config files it looks like that if you set your group list to AppAdmin then in:

```
<security-role>
    <description>Administrators</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Instead of "admin" it should be AppAdmin.

Hope this solves your problem.